# How to perform an interactive animation with Auto Layout in which you interpolate between different constraints?

Tags: swift, animation, autolayout, uigesturerecognizer

I'd like to have an interactive animation where a view transitions from one set of constraints to another as the user drags up/down the screen. The background image should shrink vertically (easy), and the profile image should change from being horizontally and vertically aligned to the background image to being anchored to the top and left corners of the background image. Is this possible?

[image: Start:]
[image: End:]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and you can see this effect in the Avvo app, for example (in the lawyer profile screen). The trick here is to smoothly transition from one set of constraints to another.

Here's an outline of how to do this:

1. add a `UIScrollView`. Add the view you want to animate as a subview to the scroll view.
2. Make your view controller implement
   `UIScrollViewDelegate`
3. In the delegate method
   `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)`, update the constraints' constants as
   needed.
4. Also in that method, when contentOffset crosses a
   threshold value, flip to a different set of constraints, by setting
   their `active` property to true or false.
5. To keep the view (the headshot image, in my example), pinned to the top as you scroll, just continuously update its top spacing constraints based on the `contentOffset.y` value.

Achieving a perfectly smooth transition may take some trial and error, but it definitely can be done!

Here are the screenshots showing the transition as you scroll up:

[image: screenshot 1]  [image: screenshot 2]  [image: screenshot 3]

Comment: The only problem is that I can't use the constant property to interpolate between positions for the profile image, because I'm changing the anchor (center.y -> left, center.x -> top). In Avvo, the lawyer's portrait retains the same anchor, which is why it works in that example.

Comment: Is changing the anchor really necessary though? I updated my answer with some additional details.

Comment: Yes, because it is going from being centered in the screen to being aligned to the left of the screen. You can't achieve that just by modifying the constant (not without a lot of device-specific code at least).

Comment: If you only use left-alignment, setting its value to `(screenwidth-viewwidth)/2.0` will center the view. From there, you can animate the constraint to a smaller value (which would align the view to the left side of screen).

Comment: I could hack it that way, but then changing that constant will still require device specific code and some guessing, since not all screen/orientation widths are the same. To make matters more complicated, there are several labels I also need to move with new anchors. That's why I can't really use this idea. I just didn't want to make the question too convoluted.

Comment: You can get the screen width programmatically at runtime, that seems pretty device-agnostic to me. I'm not suggesting hardcoding it :)